# Complex Flow Field of a Vortex Sheet at Varying Angles

Tags: complex-analysis, mathematical-physics, fluid-dynamics, branch-cuts

I want to compute the velocity field induced by a vortex sheet, connecting the two points 1 and $z_B$, in the complex plane $z=z_1+i z_2$, see Fig. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp0li.png) below. The complex conjugate of the velocity field is given by

$u^*= -\frac{i}{2 \pi} \int_1^{z_B} \frac{dz'}{z-z'}$.

Evaluation of the integral and parametrization of the upper integration limit to $z_B=1+\exp(i \beta)$ leads to

$ u^*= \frac{i}{2 \pi} \ln\left( \frac{z-1-\exp(i \beta)}{z-1} \right)$.

[Sketch of the vortex sheet (red) in the complex plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp0li.png)

Everything works as expected for $\beta=0$, see Fig. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMcC8.png).

[Real and imaginary part of complex conjugate $ u^*$ (left) and resulting velocity field $u$ (right) for $\beta=0$.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMcC8.png)

However, if I set $\beta$ to different values ($\beta \in [0, \pi/2]$) I get some troubles, see Fig. [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wTeR.png) for $\beta=\pi/4$ and Fig. [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsdkI.png) for $\beta=\pi/2$. Note, that I used the default log() and conj() functions from Matlab for computing the natural logarithm and the complex conjugate respectively.

[Real and imaginary part of complex conjugate $ u^*$ (left) and resulting velocity field $u$ (right) for $\beta=\pi/4$.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wTeR.png)

[Real and imaginary part of complex conjugate $ u^*$ (left) and resulting velocity field $u$ (right) for $\beta=\pi/2$.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsdkI.png)

My conclusion is, that I am facing some troubles with the branch-cuts. My quick-and-dirty solution so far is to evaluate $u^* \exp(-i \beta)$ instead of $u^*$, which gives the expected vortex sheet velocities. Since I am ultimately interested in evaluating more complex functions, I need to understand how to approach the described issue analytically.

I am no mathematician and I have only very little knowledge of complex analysis, so please apologize my ignorance. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved my problem by realizing that my expressions works well for $\beta=0$. Now, instead of turning the vortex sheet by an angle $\beta$, I turned the points at which I am interested in the induced velocity by $-\beta$: $y=(z-1)\exp(-i \beta)+1$. Since a vortex sheet is essentially a branch cut, which defines the jump in the tangential velocity component, I had to turn the result by another $-\beta$. In doing so, the complex conjugate of this expression yields the correct velocity field:

$u^*= \frac{i}{2 \pi} \ln\left( \frac{y-2}{y-1} \right) \exp(-i \beta) $